# Is there any plugin in sublime3 for display Perl function calling relations?

Tags: perl, editor, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I've using sublime for C coding for a while. With the help of cscope I can easily find the function/symbol calling chain (function/symbol called by which function) and jump freely. But recently I am reading perl code and cannot find a easy way to jump to the source of calling function. Don't want to search the whole project to find each time.

Is there any plugin to help display perl function calling relation?
Or is there any open source editors on mac to accomplish this?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to know `perl` `sub` calling from which location means **lineno, package and filename**? then you can use this in perl `my ($package, $filename, $line) = caller;` [caller](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html)

Comment: @AbhiNickz I think this is not about how to programmatically do something, but about how to get an IDE to do stuff in the user interface.

Comment: Take a look at [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit). I use the commercial version Komodo IDE, which does that. Possibly the free version can do it too.

Comment: @simbabque Thanks for the advice! I can give it a try.